# Inequality on bounded integer random variable

Tags: probability-theory

I am trying to solve the following problem.

Let $X$ be a non-negative integer-valued random variable such that $X \leq m$ and $E[X] = 2 m^{1-td/2}$. Proof that

$$Pr[X \geq m^{1-td/2}] \ge m^{-td/2} $$

Here is my approach:
The variance can be estimated as $$Var[X] \leq m^2 -(E[X])^2 = m^2 - 4m^{2-2td/2} $$ I first thought about using chebyshev's inequality and I get something like
$$
 Pr[|X-E[X]| \geq 1/2 E[X]] \geq 1 - \frac{Var[X]}{1/4 \cdot E[X]^2} \\
$$

But this yields to something like $ Pr[|X-E[X]| \geq -3 -m^{2td/2}$, which does not help me at all, any hints/ideas will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $p = Pr[X\ge m^{1-td/2}]$. Then
\begin{align*}
2m^{1-td/2} = E(X) &= \sum_{k=0}^m Pr[X=k]k \\
&\le \sum_{k=0}^{\lceil m^{1-td/2}\rceil-1} Pr[X=k]m^{1-td/2} + \sum_{k=\lceil m^{1-td/2}\rceil}^m Pr[X=k]m \\
&= (1-p)m^{1-td/2} + pm.
\end{align*}
Rearranging, $p(m-m^{1-td/2}) \ge m^{1-td/2}$ or equivalently
$$
p \ge \frac{m^{1-td/2}}{m-m^{1-td/2}} \ge \frac{m^{1-td/2}}{m} = m^{-td/2},
$$
as desired.

(Window into the source of the proof: "Hmm, suppose I want to make a counterexample to the claim. So I want $X$ to have very few large values yet still have a large expectation. I can try to accompish that by pushing all the small values as high as possible - up to $m^{1-td/2}$ and all the large values as high as possible - up to $m$. Oh wait, a calculation shows that even that doesn't make the expectation too big. I guess that's a proof!)

I remark that the proof doesn't really require $X$ to be integer-valued or even nonnegative, only bounded above by $m$. I also remark that you didn't define either $t$ or $d$ or give ranges for them, and in fact only the quantity $td/2$ ever matters. So for the purposes of asking the question here, it would have been better to just replace $td/2$ by $\epsilon$ and tell us what range of $\epsilon$ you care about.

Comment: thanks for your suggestions, I will improve my further questions. I thought about this approach, but only making E[X] smaller.